# Working with knockout js custom binding and jquery to have in-place edit

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

i have seen one example for in-place edit where developer use knockout js custom binding and jquery together to have in-place edit span tag. here is the js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/opd0x2vm/5/ from here anyone can see the full code and action.

i just do not understand the below portion of code which is knockout js custom binding and jquery. it will be helpfull if some one guide me to understand the code inside in **init and update function**

how a textbox is attached with span at runtime ?

```
$(function () {

    ko.bindingHandlers.dataCell = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, data, context) {
            var span = $('<span>').appendTo($(element))[0];
            ko.bindingHandlers.text.init(span, valueAccessor, allBindings, data, context);
            var input = $('<input>').appendTo($(element))[0];
            ko.bindingHandlers.textInput.init(input, valueAccessor, allBindings, data, context);
            $(element).click(function () {
                $(element).addClass('editing');
                $(input).focus().select();
            });
            $(input).blur(function () {
                $(element).removeClass('editing');
            });
        },
        update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
            var span = $(element).children('span')[0];
            ko.bindingHandlers.text.update(span, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel);
        }
    };
```

### UPDATE

when we run the program then price shown in span and when we click on price then a dynamically textbox appear on price span and when we click enter or remove pointer then change price get inserted into span and textbox remove from there.

a) i like to know how textbox dynamically placed on price span tag....which js line doing this and how?

b) how change value is getting permanent into span when we click enter or remove point...which line doing this ?

please read my 2 points and make me understand which js line doing this. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example shows how to create your own [custom binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) such as the dataCell custom binding:

```
<td class="number editable" data-bind="dataCell:price"></td>
```

As explained in the documentation a custom binding has an init and an update functions, to take the above table cell as an example. Initially when the page loads knockout call the init function which gives you access to the underlying HTML element, here you can manipulate the element, initialize jQuery UI components, etc...

The update function gets called every time the observable changes, for example in the above table cell, each time **price** changes knockout calls the update function.

Now as to what is happening inside the init function:

```
 var span = $('<span>').appendTo($(element))[0];
 ko.bindingHandlers.text.init(span, valueAccessor, allBindings, data, context);
 var input = $('<input>').appendTo($(element))[0];
 ko.bindingHandlers.textInput.init(input, valueAccessor, allBindings, data, context);
```

This is the programmatic equivalent of doing something like this:

```
<td class="number editable" data-bind="dataCell:price">
   <span data-bind="text: price"></span>
   <input data-bind="textInput: price"/>
</td>
```

The data-bind="text" is done using `ko.bindingHandlers.text.init(span, valueAccessor, allBindings, data, context);`. For more info about the [text](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/text-binding.html) and [textInput](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/textinput-binding.html) bindings see the documentation.

The update method gets called when price or quantity change, all what it does is finds this span using the jQuery code `var span = $(element).children('span')[0];`:

```
<span data-bind="text: price"></span>
```

Then calls the knockout update on the text binding to update the value. The code also includes logic to show and hide the span/input as needed.

**Update**

Both the span and the input field are created initially inside the table cell as explained above. When you click the table cell the following code adds a class to the td, this class as you can see from the CSS hides the span and shows the input

```
$(element).click(function () {
   $(element).addClass('editing');
   $(input).focus().select();
});
```

When the user navigates away from the input, it trigger blur event and the code below removes the editing class which results in the input to be hidden and the span to be shown. Please have a look at the CSS classes in the jsfiddle

```
 $(input).blur(function () {
     $(element).removeClass('editing');
 });
```

Comment: please see my updated section and answer to get it properly. thanks

Comment: i have read this thread. so curious to know where is the code which hide span and show textbox ?

Comment: @Mou The last jQuery code blocks in the answer does that, the code simply adds and removes CSS classes, CSS then shows and hides the span and input. See the styles section in the JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/opd0x2vm/5/